# Application Finder or Launcher for Mate and Gnome Session Fallback?

Tags: software-recommendation, application-finder

Mate and Gnome Session Fallback desktop environments are almost alike and really lightweight and it is the most preferred desktop environment for me.

Only thing I miss is some way to search installed applications quickly as we do using **Unity-Dash**. Since going through the **Application** menu and looking for the long list of installed application takes a long time. Some time it is so difficult to find an application. For example looking for **PCManFM** file manager, you guys know what I'm talking about. :)

Is there any Application Finder which can be installed in Mate and/or Gnome Session Fallback to search and launch installed application quickly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably are seraching for `gnome-do` application. It's easy simple and cute app for esearching for items, files and other apps in your system, and many other utilities.

Simply install it by `sudo apt-get install gnome-do`
[image]

You can also give a try for kupfer and synapse

To install Kupfer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kupfer-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kupfer
```

[image]

To install Synapse

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

[image]

[source](http://www.techdrivein.com/2010/12/kupfer-synapse-two-ubercool-gnome-do.html)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I've tried almost all and found **synapse** is the best one. In between I also got one application finder which is meant for **XFCE** but works great for all other desktop environment. Your answer will definitely help others as well :)

Comment: Its my pleasure to be helpful friend

Answer (score 5):

**Application Finder** apps suggest by [maythux](https://askubuntu.com/users/150504/maythux) are simply great and few are really recommended.

In between I also got one application finder : `xfce4-appfinder` which comes with **XFCE** desktop environment. But it is standalone `application finder` and doesn't require any additional package of **XFCE**.

To install it simply execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-appfinder
```

One single package will be installed silently and would work for all desktop environments.

Here is my image:

[image]

**Update (19-Jan-2017):**

I used [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) for almost 3 years and recently switched to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Sad to say that it's core repository no more available to install. Couldn't find any way to install in 16.04 so far.

Though I found an another nice **Application Launcher [albert](https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert)** for Ubuntu 16.04. Here are the steps to install **[albert launcher](https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert)**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/albert
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install albert
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: can you re-upload that picture?

Comment: @endolith: Thanks for notifying me about the broken image.. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **Synapse**:

> Synapse is a semantic launcher written in Vala that you can use to start applications as well as find and access relevant documents and files by making use of the Zeitgeist engine.
>   https://launchpad.net/synapse-project

Installation:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:synapse-core/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

This is like Unity-Dash, and very powerful. Once running, activate it using *CTRL-SPACE* and start typing what you need. It uses fuzzy logic to search for applications, documents, audio, places, images, and more. *ENTER* and voila, you are up and running.