# Why some software aren't detectable by the system?

Tags: apt, 13.10, launcher, synapse, application-finder

I downloaded [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) from the software center, as far as I know, everything we download from the center should be an apt package, thus it should be detectable by the system.

However, scid is not listed in the menu of installed apps, the default application finder does not find it, nor Synapse, they find everything but Scid. Why?

Comment: The downloaded packaged can not be detected by the system. It can be detected only when you install it or once you referred it or any kind of shortcut has been created. Have you installed **Scid** in your system yet?

Comment: @SauravKumar of course i did install it and I use it everyday, to run it, you have to open a terminal and type `scid`. The question however is why some software are not detectable

Comment: It is unbelievable that **scid** can not be listed even in **synapse** ;) Apart from **scid** what other software are not detectable? Did you try to search **scid** with the name something like **Shane's Chess Information Database**?

Comment: @SauravKumar So far scid is the only one that is not detectable, and yes i did search **Shane's Chess Information Database** and **Chess database with play and training functionality** which is its name in the software center, found nothing, unbelievable? install it, see if you can find it :) I'll buy you beer :P it's not only on ubuntu, I used to be on Crunchbang last year, so I think, this issue is on all debian/ubuntu based distros. I haven't tried it on other distros

Comment: You seem so confident, you'd be correct then. :) I didn't install it in my system. I just want you to try it in these **[application finder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/417093/application-finder-for-mate-and-gnome-session-fallback)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scid` package doesn't have a `.desktop` file according to [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/scid/filelist). The applications which present you with a menu of installed apps generate that menu from the `.desktop` files present on your system in the `/usr/share/applications/` or in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. If a program doesn't have a `.desktop` file in one of those directories it won't show up in the menu.

This is by design. There are a lot of programs (mostly terminal based ones) which shouldn't show up in the graphical menu. If you want this program to show up in the application menu you can make a `.desktop` file for it.

Also if you feel that this program is that kind of program which should automatically install a `.desktop` file for itself you may file a bug report.

Comment: **+1** for you definitive answer. Exactly the answer **OP** wants to know. :)

Comment: thank you, I'll write a `.desktop` file and I'll file a bug report, because it should automatically install a `.desktop` file for itself, Scid is not a terminal based software

Answer (score 2):

First off, the Ubuntu Software Centre and the Package Manager are two separate things - there are some programs that belong to both, but not everything does. (For the most part, for instance, if something can be paid for in USC, it's not going to be available in one of the repositories)

In the specific case of `scid`, it is indeed an `apt` package, but just because that is the case, doesn't mean that it will necessarily install a shortcut to the Dash when you download it. You do, however, have a couple of alternatives for running it:

- Run from a terminal, as you already have, by opening up a terminal and typing `scid`;
- Open the run prompt by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and type `scid` there;
- Create your own shortcut to put in the Dash.

This last one can be done quite easily using the `alacarte` program. Type `sudo apt-get install alacarte` into a terminal. Once it has installed, type `alacarte` to open.

Once it has opened, click the "New Item" button on the right. As a command you should type `scid`, for the name you type whatever you want to call the shortcut (most likely `Scid`.) In addition, you can choose a custom icon by clicking the small box in the top-left of the properties prompt. As a suggestion, you can use for example one of the images in `/usr/share/scid/html/bitmaps` - if you browse there you will see a series of icons representing each chess piece (more generally speaking, you should be able to choose pretty much any image to go here, but you will want it to be something small for an icon). Click OK, close Alacarte and your new shortcut should be in the Dash now.

If you want to edit the entry you have created later on, open `alacarte` again. Your shortcut will be in the "Other" section to the left of the window.

Comment: **+1** for your constructive thought and idea. :)